# I can't delete town in Scenario Editor if it has oil rig in nearby waters

Tags: openttd

Using scenario editor, I created a town near waters and put an oil rig in waters.

When I try to delete town, now it refuses that it has station or objects using city name. It do not let me delete oil rig also in any way. I renamed oil rig also to give it separate name from city name it inherited but no success.

I have many other towns and industries in the scenario so starting a new scenario is not the best option.

Let me know if I can just delete couple of towns with oil rigs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem in the latest release of Open TTD, 1.3.1.

Creating a body of water, neighbouring town and oil rig I see that as you say you can't remove the town because of the associated oil rig, however it is possible to remove the oil rig using the **demolish** (**bomb**) tool:

[image: Initial setup of oil rig]

[image: Demolishing the oil rig]

[image: Deleting the town]

[image: The barren wasteland that was Gaming.SE]

Comment: Thanks, let me try 'bomb' and revert. I will revert with my experience soon.

Comment: It worked :) I was looking for delete for rigs in same way as city has. Thanks